# Why does it take so long to execute a stored procedure using ado.net / EF 6?

Tags: sql-server, ado.net, entity-framework-6, azure-sql-database, query-performance

Environment:

- ASP.NET MVC 5.2.3.0
- SQL Server 2014 (v12.0.2000.8)
- Entity Framework 6

hosted on Azure

We have one page that gets data from the database using a stored procedure.

Lately we’ve noticed that some time this page loads about 20 secs. So we started to investigate the problem. I’ve tried to execute this stored procedure directly from Management Studio and it took 150 ms+-:

[image]

So next thing I did is create a console application that connects to the Azure SQL database and executes this stored procedure:

[image]

I've also tried to use `SqlQuery` from EF 6:

[image]

Same thing.

Important thing: this is not permanent problem. Sometimes this problem occurs, sometimes it works just fine - 50/50.

I've checked the database load in the Azure portal - it is about 50% dtu usage (during this performance issue). But I don’t think this is related to database load because it executes fast from Management Studio.

Currently I have no idea what is the problem so I need help. I would like to notice that a lot of employees use this page (that executes the stored procedure) all the time. Maybe this is somehow related to problem.

So question: why does it take so long to execute this stored procedure using ado.net / EF?

Answer (score 0):

Do some debugging.

Potential culprits include, mostly:

- Database side locking that is not released fast, making a SP waiting.
- Parameter sniffing where a query path is not optimal for a specific set of parameters (which may lead to locking blocking you). This is a SP problem - someone does not write proper SQL for cases like that.

The info you give is irrelevant. See... SP's are NOT EXECUTED IN EF6 - EF6 fowrards them to ADO.NET which sends them to the database. As you say they work slow, IN THE DATABASE, any C# level debugging is as useless as the menu from my local Pizzeria for this particular question. YOu have to go down and debug and analyze what happens on the database.

The SSMS screenshot you provide is totally useless - you need to run the SP in SSMS, for a case it happens, and then use.... the query plan and proper nalaysis traces to see what happens.

Comment: I'm sure that all parameters that I pass to Stored Procedure are the same within SSMS and Visual studio(ADO.NET). And execution time it this case in SSMS - 150ms, Visual studio - 20 sec. So this is not related to parameters.

Regarding your suggestion: I can not reproduce this while executing SP from SSMS so I don't understand how "query plan and proper analysis" will help me here.

Comment: Regarding "Database side locking that is not released fast, making a SP waiting."
Can you please be more clear?
How to investigate it?

Comment: Database side, like always. If a query needs a special lock and can not get it it waits - if other queries are slow, that can lead to overloading of a db server fast.

Comment: I understand your point, but here what i don't understand.
If some query locks some resources that are needed in my SP, in this case sp would execute for a long time from both: SSMS and Visual studio.
Am I right?

Comment: And you test at the same time? Remember what you said: "Sometimes this problem occurs, sometimes it works just fine"

Comment: Yes. I tested at the same time. Regarding what i sad I ment that some time it take the same time to execute from SSMS and Visual studio. But some time execution time is much bigger in Visual studio.